# CentOS 7 is not detecting my network card, listing as UNCLAIMED

Tags: linux, centos, networkmanager, ethernet, nmcli

I installed CentOS 7 minimal on a server. It has two NICs.
However, one of them doesn't appear to be working. It also appears as UNCLAIMED.
Its not showing when i use commands to list network devices, like ifconfig and ip -a

The other nic installed is a PCI Express card. I cant get it to work...
Please, can someone help me?

ip link:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:23:ae:b6:65:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

lshw -class network:

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:23:ae:b6:65:cd
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full ip=192.168.17.12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:d800(size=256) memory:feaff000-feafffff memory:fdff0000-fdffffff memory:feac0000-feadffff

  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: VT6120/VT6121/VT6122 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
       vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 82
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e800(size=256) memory:febffc00-febffcff
```

Comment: Are you able to load the kernel module through `sudo modprobe -v via-velocity`

Comment: UNCLAIMED means your kernel doesn't have the driver for it. Either try to find a vendor driver or use CentOS 8.

Comment: Well, there isnt drivers that exists for this card so we had to buy another one, now this one is working just fine. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just want everyone that is reading this that the solution for me was switching the network card.

It was a problem with the NIC itself. I tested in another OS just to be sure. Tested on Windows to be more assertive, since Linux do have some problems with drivers in some ocassions, and i got to the conclusion that the problem was with the network card itself since even with a Windows OS + With drivers it wasnt working.

After changing the NIC to a newer one everything worked fine.